# Change hover button class from onClick of other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

That button changes "TE LAAT" into "NU BETALEN" on hover with CSS, which works like a charm. Now I want the "TE LAAT" text to change only when you click the "collapsible-header" div. So when that div becomes active (I added that class now, but the active class toggles when you click it.) the text in the button changes to NU BETALEN.

Basically change the "TE LAAT" into the data-hover or data-active "NU BETALEN" when the div collapsible-header also has the active class.

```css
.collapsible-header.active {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

/* .button */
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 7rem;
    margin-top: 3.7em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5 6px;
    border: 3px solid #EE6E73;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #EE6E73;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7rem !important;
}

.button span {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: ;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .4s,opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: .4s,opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: .4s,opacity .6s;
    transition: .4s,opacity .6s;
}

/* :before */

.button:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -o-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    transform: translate(-150%,0);
}

/* :after */

.button:after {
    content: attr(data-active);
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(150%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(150%,0);
    -o-transform: translate(150%,0);
    transform: translate(150%,0);
}

/* Span on :hover and :active */

.button:hover span,
.button:active span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

/*
    We show :before pseudo-element on :hover
    and :after pseudo-element on :active
*/

.button:hover:before,
.button:active:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

/*
  We hide :before pseudo-element on :active
*/

.button:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -o-transform: translate(-150%,0);
    transform: translate(-150%,0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/css/ghpages-materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="button right" type="button" data-hover="NU BETALEN" data-active="NU BETALEN TWEE"><span>TE LAAT</span></button>
<div class="collapsible-header active">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does "works like a charm" mean that it doesn't work at all? `:-)`

Comment: The button changed correctly on hover, but not when I clicked the other div. The button itself worked like a charm. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to replace `.button:hover`/`.button:active` with `.button.active` in your CSS, then add the JS below to toggle its .active class:

```
$('.collapsible-header').click(function(){
  $('.button').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working, eventough it seems so easy now haha.

I made a live demo: http://app.roelofplas.nl/admin/facturen-betalen.php

Could you please explain a bit more wich .button:hover / .button:active tags u mean? Or do u mean all of them?